# Combining fields for date of birth to save into the db

Tags: php, mysql, date

I currently have a form that asks for each of these in separate dropdowns.

Day | Month | Year

When I am inserting into the database, I perform the following but all it inserts is 00-00-0000.

```
$_POST['date'] = $_POST['dob_day'].'-'.$_POST['dob_month'].'-'.$_POST['dob_year'];

//I then do my insert and I'm inserting this..

mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date'])
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Do you get actual numbers/number-strings returned from the web-page?

Comment: Your code is vurnerable to SQL injections. Please fix that problem first. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I honestly didn't check but every other bit of data is coming across and storing just fine into the db so I would assume it is..

Comment: I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string` though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't assign anything to $_POST, that's super bad practice.
2. Dates in mySQL should be formatted `YYYY-MM-DD`.

`$date = $_POST['dob_year'] . '-' . $_POST['dob_month'] . '-' . $_POST['dob_day'];`

Comment: Brilliant pickup - completely missed that #2! Trying to accept the answer but have to wait 7 minutes :)

Comment: You are right: `Don't assign anything to $_POST, that's super bad practice.` So please don't provide code how to use it.

Comment: @juergend what are you on about?

Answer (score 0):

you're assigning the data to a POST which isn't correct.

`$date = $_POST['dob_day'].'-'.$_POST['dob_month'].'-'.$_POST['dob_year'];`

then insert `$date`

Comment: No problem assigning to POST, you still can use it as usual array, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks David Nguyen - just that the MySQL format is yyyy-mm-dd which I completely forgot! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your values are empty after this, you are not using POST correctly. I changed it up a little bit to make it more readable:

```
$day = $_POST['dob_day'];
$month = $_POST['dob_month'];
$year = $_POST['dob_year'];

$date = $day . '/' . $month . '/' . $year;
$insert = "INSERT INTO table('dob') VALUES('$date')";
// then run $insert
```